# Function not receiving updated redux state even on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently using Redux, Redux Thunk with NextJS and been trying to figure out how to access the updated redux state inside a function of a functional component.

As you can see in my code below, in the `handleSubmit` function, I want to update the redux state and then check the state value and decided which route it should take the user to.

Previously in my old project, using `mapStateToProps` with a Class component, I was able to access the updated redux state inside my `handleSubmit` function however when using a functional component both options (`useSelector` hook or `mapStateToProps` with `connect()`) doesn't seem to work.

At first I thought the component wasn't re-rendering however when checking the state in `useEffect()`, I can see that the state is getting updated and the component is able to view the updated values.

Is there something I'm clearly missing or is this way not possible with functional components?

**loginPage.tsx**

```js
import LoginForm, { FormData } from 'components/Forms/LoginForm';
import Layout from 'components/Layout';
import { FORM_ERROR } from 'final-form';
import StatusCodes from 'lib/enums/statusCodes';
import { storeAuthToken } from 'lib/helpers/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from 'redux/store';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { auth } = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => ({ auth: state.auth }));

  const handleSubmit = async (values: FormData) => {
    if (values && values.username && values.password) {
      try {
        // Updates redux store
        await storeAuthToken(dispatch, values.username, values.password);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error === StatusCodes.BadRequest) {
          return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Sorry, you have entered incorrect details. Please try again' };
        } else {
          return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Sorry, there was an issue trying to log you in' };
        }
      }

      // Can't see updated values
      console.log('Auth: ', auth);

      if (auth.parsedJwt && auth.parsedJwt.changePassword) {
        router.push({ pathname: '/update-password' });
        return;
      }

      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Can see the updated values
    console.log('New Auth: ', auth);
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <Layout hideProfileMenu title="Login">
      <LoginForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

I've attached the store and reducer incase I've set it up wrong.

**store.tsx**

```js
import Auth from 'lib/interfaces/auth';
import { Context, createWrapper, HYDRATE, MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, CombinedState, combineReducers, createStore, Dispatch, Reducer } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch, ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from './auth/reducer';

export interface ApplicationState {
  auth: Auth
}

const isDebug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const bindMiddleware = (middleware: ThunkMiddleware) => {
  if (isDebug) {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension');
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(middleware));
  }

  return applyMiddleware(middleware);
};

const combinedReducer: Reducer<ApplicationState> = combineReducers<ApplicationState>({
  auth: authReducer
});

const reducer = (state: ApplicationState, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState: CombinedState<ApplicationState> = {
      ...state,
      ...action.payload
    };

    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};

const makeStore: MakeStore<ApplicationState> = (_context: Context) => createStore(reducer as Reducer<ApplicationState, AnyAction>, bindMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));

export const wrapper = createWrapper<ApplicationState>(makeStore, { debug: isDebug });
```

**reducer.tsx**

```js
import Auth from 'lib/interfaces/auth';
import { Reducer } from 'redux';
import { ActionTypes, AuthAction } from './actions';

const reducer: Reducer<Auth, AuthAction> = (state: Auth = {} as Auth, action: AuthAction): Auth => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.UpdateToken:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { token: action.token });
    case ActionTypes.UpdateRefreshToken:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { refreshToken: action.refreshToken });
    case ActionTypes.UpdateParsedJwt:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { parsedJwt: action.parsedJwt });
    case ActionTypes.UpdateUuid:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { uuid: action.uuid });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: The redux dispatcher runs asynchronously so handleSubmit may finish before the auth value is updated. Since this function also pushes a new path to the router, I would assume that this will unload the login component and therefore the useEffect underneath will no longer fire.

Does the useEffect fire with the new auth value if you remove the router.push calls?

Comment: Alternatively you could have the storeAuthToken function return the auth value to use exclusively in the handleSubmit function as well as dispatching it.

Comment: @andyd_28 The useEffect still fires with the new auth value when I remove the router.push calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to return the auth object from 'storeAuthToken' as it keeps the error handling and result in the same logical flow, and it fixes the asynchronous issue identified in the comments.

```js
import LoginForm, { FormData } from 'components/Forms/LoginForm';
import Layout from 'components/Layout';
import { FORM_ERROR } from 'final-form';
import StatusCodes from 'lib/enums/statusCodes';
import { storeAuthToken } from 'lib/helpers/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from 'redux/store';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const handleSubmit = async (values: FormData) => {
    if (values && values.username && values.password) {
      try {
        // Updates redux store
        const authResult = await storeAuthToken(dispatch, values.username, values.password);
          
        if (authResult.parsedJwt && authResult.parsedJwt.changePassword) {
          router.push({ pathname: '/update-password' });
          return;
        }
        
      } catch (error) {
        if (error === StatusCodes.BadRequest) {
          return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Sorry, you have entered incorrect details. Please try again' };
        } else {
          return { [FORM_ERROR]: 'Sorry, there was an issue trying to log you in' };
        }
      }

      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout hideProfileMenu title="Login">
      <LoginForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```